# How to get list of devices and connect using BluetoothLE plugin in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bluetooth, ionic4

I'm using BluetoothLE plugin and I want to get a list of active Bluetooth devices and click to connect with the device using ionic 4. Hello, I'm using BluetoothLE plugin and I want to get a list of active Bluetooth devices and click to connect with the device using ionic 4.

```
....
import { BluetoothLE } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-le/ngx';
import { Platform, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
....

statusMessage: string;

constructor(public bluetoothle: BluetoothLE,
    public platform: Platform,
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    public toastController: ToastController) {
    this.platform.ready().then((readySource) => {

      console.log('Platform ready from', readySource);

      this.bluetoothle.initialize().subscribe(ble => {
        console.log('ble', ble.status) // logs 'enabled'
      });

    });
  }

  adapterInfo() {
    this.bluetoothle.getAdapterInfo().then((success) => {
      console.log("adapterInfo: " + success);
      this.setStatus(success.name);
    })
  }

  startScan() {
    let params = {
      "services": [
        "180D",
        "180F"
      ],
      "allowDuplicates": true,
    }
    this.bluetoothle.startScan(params).subscribe((success) => {
      console.log("startScan: " + success);
      this.setStatus(success.address);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("error: " + error);
      this.scanError(error);
    })
  }

  stopScan() {
    this.bluetoothle.stopScan().then((resp) => {
      console.log("stopScan: " + resp);
      this.setStatus(resp.status);
    })
  }

  retrieveConnected() {
    let params = {
      "services": [
        "180D",
        "180F"
      ]
    }

    this.bluetoothle.retrieveConnected(params).then((resp) => {
      console.log("retrieveConnected: " + resp);
      this.setStatus("retrieveConnected");
    })
  }

  // If location permission is denied, you'll end up here
  async scanError(error: string) {
    this.setStatus('Error ' + error);
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'Error scanning for Bluetooth low energy devices',
      position: 'middle',
      duration: 5000
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  setStatus(message: string) {
    console.log("message: " + message);
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.statusMessage = message;
    });
  }
```

in HTML

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-button (click)="adapterInfo()">AdapterInfo</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="startScan()">StartScan</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="stopScan()">StopScan</ion-button>
  <ion-button (click)="retrieveConnected()">RetrieveConnected</ion-button>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <p>{{ statusMessage }}</p>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Please Help...

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to get a list of the device when start Bluetooth scan.

Comment: are you getting an error, or what doesn't work, i.e what happens and what should happen instead?

Comment: when I click on scan start I'm getting [object][object] error.

Comment: where are you running this, on device?

Comment: yup in android device, well I did console.log("startScan: " + JSON.stringify(success)); so i got status "scanStarted"

Comment: okay, so where is the error presented if you say now that it's a success?

Comment: I just write code and building an app when it is done will show you...just a few min's

Comment: I got this error application registration failed

Comment: The error you are talking about keeps changing... Without digging into too much, if that error is thrown when running the app, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with bluetooth? Anyway, your code looks fine if you are running on device and have bluetooth enabled.

Comment: I solved error( application registration failed ), the solution is location permission required for Bluetooth. still testing

Comment: ok, you should always check such things like in these plugins in your code. Like for example you need to add a check that user has bluetooth enabled before trying to use the plugin or you will get errors. there is a function for that: https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle#isenabled

Comment: In the end, I did not get any solutions,

Comment: so what is the error now? You are concatenating the error also, so it doesn't really help, use `,` instead of `+` in your console.log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197660/discussion-between-user9088454-and-ajt-82).

Comment: @user9088454 have you found any solution?

Comment: Hi, i am having same issue. can you please suggest the solution if you found.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the param "services": ["180D", "180F" ] on startScan method. Because it is scanning an unknown services.

Comment: Will that answer the question?